# CSS ripple effect on Hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, hover

I have a button where I'd like a slightly transparent overlay to 'glide through' the button on hover.

There is something called the 'ripple effect' that you usually can achieve by clicking on a button.

Like here: https://codepen.io/tomma5o/pen/zwyKya

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <a data-animation="ripple">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
:root {
    /* if u want to change the color of
     * the ripple change this value
    */
    --color-ripple: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

body {
    background: #36353c;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
*[data-animation="ripple"] {
    position: relative; /*Position relative is required*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    outline: none;:root {
    /* if u want to change the color of
     * the ripple change this value
    */
    --color-ripple: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

body {
    background: #36353c;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
*[data-animation="ripple"] {
    position: relative; /*Position relative is required*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #e570e7 0%, #79f1fc 100%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-family: roboto, helvetica;
    font-weight: 200;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
    /*border-radius: 50px;*/
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"]::selection {
    background: transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
}

    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #e570e7 0%,#79f1fc 100%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-family: roboto, helvetica;
    font-weight: 200;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 50px;*/
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

*[data-animation="ripple"]::selection {
    background: transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
const isMobile = window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/) && window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/)[0] === "Mobile";
const event = isMobile ? "touchstart" : "click";

const button = document.querySelectorAll('*[data-animation="ripple"]'),
            container = document.querySelector(".container");

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    const currentBtn = button[i];

    currentBtn.addEventListener(event, function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        const button = e.target,
                    rect = button.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    originalBtn = this,
                    btnHeight = rect.height,
                    btnWidth = rect.width;
        let posMouseX = 0,
                posMouseY = 0;

        if (isMobile) {
            posMouseX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - rect.left;
            posMouseY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - rect.top;
        } else {
            posMouseX = e.x - rect.left;
            posMouseY = e.y - rect.top;
        }

        const baseCSS =  `position: absolute;
                                            width: ${btnWidth * 2}px;
                                            height: ${btnWidth * 2}px;
                                            transition: all linear 700ms;
                                            transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
                                            border-radius: 50%;
                                            background: var(--color-ripple);
                                            top:${posMouseY - btnWidth}px;
                                            left:${posMouseX - btnWidth}px;
                                            pointer-events: none;
                                            transform:scale(0)`

        var rippleEffect = document.createElement("span");
        rippleEffect.style.cssText = baseCSS;

        //prepare the dom
        currentBtn.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.appendChild(rippleEffect);

        //start animation
        setTimeout( function() { 
            rippleEffect.style.cssText = baseCSS + `transform:scale(1); opacity: 0;`;
        }, 5);

        setTimeout( function() {
            rippleEffect.remove();
            //window.location.href = currentBtn.href;
        },700);
    })
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar without having to click on the button but just hovering over it?

Comment: hmm do you want the ripple origin to be wherever the mouse enters? or a fixed, centred origin?

Comment: I edited the answer for an effect closer to the original. Please check if that works for you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Replace line 2 of JS:**

```
const event = isMobile ? "touchstart" : "click";
```

**with:**

```
const event = isMobile ? "touchstart" : "mouseover";
```

That would do the job.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you want the ripple origin to be fixed (e.g. from the middle) instead of from wherever the mouse enters, the answer is much simpler and requires no javascript: just stack a semi-transparent rounded pseudo-element and animate the scale on hover.

```css
body {
 background: #36353c;
}

.container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 margin: auto;
}
.ripple{
 position: relative; /*Position relative is required*/
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 outline: none;
 padding: 20px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, #e570e7 0%,#79f1fc 100%);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 14px;
 font-family: roboto, helvetica;
 font-weight: 200;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-decoration: none;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.ripple:hover:before{
 animation: ripple 1s ease;
}

.ripple:before{
 content:"";
 position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
 width:100%; height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius:50%;
 transform:scale(0);
}

@keyframes ripple{
 from{transform:scale(0); opacity:1;}
 to{transform:scale(3);opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a class="ripple">Hover Me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be the best thing possible, but it looks kinda weird, nothing similar to what happens on click.

Comment: @Radical_Activity there you go, I just edited the fiddle for something closer to the original.